# Error when building with Gradle: Cause: error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

When building with Gradle I am receiving an Error:

```
(Cause: error=2, No such file or directory)
```

and the application is not installed. I am using Android Studio 3.1 and Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: show the details of error: which file not found, on which stage, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing this same problem . I debugged it by adding the missing directory whose path was as follow :
/home/sunarcneel/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/mips64el-linux-android4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64.
There were some folders and files missing which I took from the fellow developer's desktop where the studio was setup correctly.
Please check the ndk bundle folder of thge desktop.You will get your answer.